# sum list-column of matrices (from nested data.frame) using R, dplyr

Tags: r, list, dplyr, nested

I have a grouped `data.frame`, with a column `m` that contains 2x2 matrices, as in this example:

```
library(tidyverse)
d <- data.frame(g=c(1,1,2,2),x1=c(1,1,1,1),x2=c(1,1,1,1))
d_by <- d  %>%  group_by(g) %>% nest %>% 
  mutate(m = map(data,data.matrix))
d_by$m %>% str
```

How can I add the matrices in list-column m into a single matrix?

I tried using

```
d_by %>% summarise(sum(m))
```

But got the error message:

```
Error in sum(m) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

Comment: You can just do  `d_by$m[[1]] + d_by$m[[2]]`

Comment: Tks, but in my actual code, d_by has many rows. So I need a solution for arbitrary G, with g={1,...,G}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce` for an arbitrary number of matrices

```
purrr::reduce(d_by$m, `+`)
```

Answer (score 2):

Or in `base R`

```
Reduce(`+`, d_by$m)
```